# Spock Integration Test fails when run with other integration tests-succeeds in isolation using integration:spock

Tags: grails, integration-testing, spock

I am adding a first spock integration test to an existing set of tests for a grails 2.1.1 application.  The test runs and tests pass when run using:

```
grails test-app integration:spock CreditServiceSpec
```

(Yes, everything is in the default package - fixing this is a ton of work that will not be approved...file under technical debt.)

However, when I run all the tests (grails test-app), unit test pass, spock unit tests pass, integration tests pass, but I get the following failure for spock integration:

> | Completed 818 integration tests, 0 failed in 104001ms
>   | Running 1 spock test...
>   | Failure:  CreditServiceSpec
>   |  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: failed to invoke constructor: public org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.support.GrailsTestAutowirer(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) with arguments: [] reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>       at grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec.$spock_initializeSharedFields(IntegrationSpec.groovy:33)
>   | Completed 0 spock test, 0 failed in 33ms
>   | Tests PASSED - view reports in /Users/***/projects/GrailsPlugins/DomainServices/target/test-reports

I get the exact same exception whether I run the full test I built or the following, very strip down example:

```
import grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec

class CreditServiceSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    def setup() {}
    def cleanup() {}

    public void "sample"() {
        setup:"Nothing to do here."

        expect:"This is the truest of truths..."
        true == true
    }
}
```

I did crack open IntegrationSpec and looked at line 33:

```
@Shared private autowirer = new GrailsTestAutowirer(applicationContext)
```

But determining how/why the applicationContext is not being passed in properly is beyond me and, perhaps, is the thrust of my question.

Has anyone encountered this kind of behavior and found a way to get spock integration to play nice with other tests?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Grails 2.1.1 had [several issues](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9432) with Spock tests in the Integration scope.  [Jeff's comment](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9463?focusedCommentId=72547&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-72547) and [Peter's](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9463?focusedCommentId=72553&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-72553) in particular sound like the issue you were having; basically the ApplicationHolder was null or an empty list.

The parent task lists Grails 2.2.5 as the fix version. Any chance you can upgrade to that (or some even later version) and see if the problem persists?

There have also been cases where a simple `grails clean` [has fixed issues like this](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-0-spock-and-Specification-vs-IntegrationSpec-td4223950.html).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  `grails clean` was not a fix in this case.  While I hope to move to 2.3.x the time to live for this application/case may prevent that from getting sufficient priority.  I will be sure to report back here if this becomes reality and the version does provide a fix.

Comment: I feel you there. Something I didn't know that may help sway your particular powers that be: it's totally possible to have Grails apps running different versions on the same Tomcat server. If this project is contained in its own app, you might just try cloning off a copy and running it under a different Grails version. gvm can be super-helpful for getting another Grails version up on your machine quickly without a lot of hassle. http://gvmtool.net/

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the exact same symptom.

I was using the BuildTestData plugin and used the @Build annotation in a IntegrationSpec, but using the @Build with use a transformation wich extended the @TestFor transformation which is incompatible with the Intengration runtime.

So just remove the @Build annotations and it will run.